# Error de sintaxis en script MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

He creado un script sencillo en `MySQL`.... la idea es crear un procedimiento que muestre los datos del ultimo registro de una tabla especifica.

Este seria el código del script:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS mostrarUltimaAlta;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE mostrarUltimaAlta ()

BEGIN

SELECT id, nombre_completo, correo FROM USUARIOS WHERE id = (select max(id));

END;

$$
DELIMITER;
```

La idea es que se haga un `drop` inicial para eliminar algún procedimiento similar ya creado.

Luego con `delimiter` creo el contenido del `script`...

durante el procedimiento hago una `select` para que muestre los campos deseados del ultimo registro insertado.

Finalmente finaliza el procedimiento...

Una vez finalizado guardo el código del script y salgo de `MySQL`... y desde el `prompt` trato de lanzar el script:

```
 usuario@ubuntu: mysql -u root -p DB_MENSAJES <script.sql
```

Pero al ejecutarlo me da este error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 12: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER' at line 1

No logro ver que hay de mal en el código para que no funcione el delimiter... podéis ayudarme? gracias!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te falta un espacio entre `DELIMITER` y `;`:

```
DELIMITER ;
```

Pero además, vas a notar que la consulta SQL no te va a dar el resultado esperado. Tienes que agregar el `FROM` en la subconsulta para que te de los resultados correctos:

```
SELECT id, nombre_completo, correo 
  FROM USUARIOS 
 WHERE id = (select max(id)
               from usuarios);
```

O, puedes evitar la subconsulta usando `LIMIT`:

```
select id, nombre_completo, correo
  from usuarios
 order by id desc
 limit 1;
```

Comment: gracias! era justo ese el problema :)